# Does Ethereum proof of stake still use hashing?

Tags: proof-of-stake

I am trying to understand the Ethereum proof of stake protocol, I got a general idea however, still have some confusion.

What exactly means proposing a block. Does the winner validator still require to do the hashing work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What exactly means proposing a block?

Proposing a block means telling the blockchain which block should be added next. A node might attempt to prioritize its own transactions by including them early in blocks added to the blockchain, making it a dishonest node. A fair block proposal of a node follows a random selection of the transactions among the set of pending transactions the node is aware of. The more stakes a validator owns, the more it has chances of being selected as a proposer. So, if a node starts acting dishonestly, it is penalized from the tokens that it staked.

> Does the winner validator still require to do the hashing work?

Yes. The difference between PoS and PoW is that in PoW, everyone competes with each other to do the hashing work. Whereas in PoS, only the selected validator will do the work.